# Change Gnome-Tweaks through terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome

I have an idea to change the appearance of my Linux machine automatically.

Is there any way I can change Gnome-tweaks settings from terminal/bash script?
Some documentation of all settings described would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Start the gnome tweaks in your terminal with the verbose option, so you see what kind of setting you're actually changing.

```
$ gnome-tweaks -v
```

Example Output after changing the font scaling factor:

```
Change: org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor -> 1.3
```

With this information, we can now proceed to change these settings in the terminal/bash script:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.3
```

To ensure that the setting has been correctly changed, we can get the new value the following way:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```